# Could anyone correct my code? Using method and arrays

Tags: java

I want to know what is wrong with my code.

I have to use overloading in `getBonus()`
so I convert integer 1 to double 1.0 
but this program says

```
symbol:   method getBonus(int)
  location: class Bouns
```

and

```
symbol:   method getBonus(double)
  location: class Bouns
```

why?

This code is homework, and the homework question is below:

> Q4. A company need to write a program calculates and displays bonus
>   amounts to pay  various types of employees. There are two separate
>   departments, numbered 1 and 2. Department 1 employees are get 20%
>   bonus if they work more than 10 years in the  company, otherwise they
>   get nothing. In department 2 employees get a bonus based on the
>   employee type:
>
> a. Employee work as part-time get bonus 250$ b. Employee work as
>   full-time get bonus 700$.
>
> Assume the employee type will be read from user where ‘P’ for
>   part-time and ‘F’ for full-time.
>
> Write a set of two overloaded methods called getBonus() that works
>   with the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bouns
{
    final static int DEPT1_EMP = 250;
    final static int DEPT2_EMP = 500;
    static Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double [] salary_Dept1=new double[DEPT1_EMP];
        double [] salary_Dept2=new double[DEPT2_EMP];
        fillArray(salary_Dept1);
        boolean done = false;
        double d ;
        char yORn;
        do {
            fillArray(salary_Dept1); System.out.println("Enter department: ");
            int dept = read.nextInt();

            if (dept == 1) {
                getBonus((double)dept);// Here is the problem
            }
            else if ( dept == 2)
                getBonus(dept);
            System.out.println("do you want to continue ? y/n ");
            yORn = read.next.charAt(0);
            if (yORn == 'n')
                done = true;
        } while (!done);
    }

    public static void fillArray(double[] a) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = read.nextDouble(); 
    }
    public static void fillArray2(double[] b) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            b[i]= read.nextDouble(); 
    }
    public static void getBounds(double x) {
        int num;
        for (int i = 1; i <= DEPT1_EMP; i++) {
            System.out.print("How many years have the employee No. "+k);
            num = read.next();
            if (num > 10)
                salary_Dept1[k] = salary_Dept1[k] + (20/100)*salary_Dept1[k];
        }
    }
    public static void getBounds(int x) {
        char fORp;
        for (int i = 1; i <= DEPT2_EMP; i++) {
            System.out.print("the empolyee number "+i+" if s/he works full-time or part=time (F/P)?");
            fORp = read.next.charAt(0);
            if (fOrp == 'F') {
                salary_Dept2 [i] = salary_Dept2[i]+700;
            }
            else if (fOrp == 'P'){
                salary_Dept2 [i] = salary_Dept2[i]+250;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getBonus expects an int....

Comment: Please correctly indent your code, and describe the problem that you are having.

Comment: All the IDEs allow formatting the code with a single keyboard shortcut or mouse click. You could at least do that before asking a question, to make your code readable. This would also help YOU reading and understanding your own code.

Comment: @DGomez do you mean getBonus  accept only int ?? because I have two getBonus one for double and the another for int

Comment: @BaileyS it is a home work and I will write it down

Comment: Actually I tried to post correctly indented code here, but all the time I got the same indention problems as OP. I think something is wrong with [code] tag here.

Comment: @ferrerverck: never use tabs in code, paste the correctly indented code in the text box, select it, and hit Ctrl-K (or Cmd-K on MacOS). No problem for me, and I post a lot of code here.

Comment: @ferrerverck I am waiting, please help me, and you can do it as what JB Nizet said

Comment: @user3053059 Posting the homework question that you are trying to solve does not count as providing the problem you are having with the code. For the most part, people on StackOverflow do not like solving people's homework for them... this is why your question has been modded down so much. Anyways, the compiler told you what is wrong... calling methods that don't exist. The methods are named `getBounds`, but you call `getBonus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While fixing your indentation in my IDE, I saw a bunch of compile errors you need to fix.  I commented all the areas that need fixing.

```
public class Bouns {

    final static int DEPT1_EMP = 250;
    final static int DEPT2_EMP = 500;
    static Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] salary_Dept1 = new double[DEPT1_EMP];
        double[] salary_Dept2 = new double[DEPT2_EMP];
        fillArray(salary_Dept1);
        boolean done = false;
        double d;
        char yORn;
        do {
            fillArray(salary_Dept1);
            System.out.println("Enter department: ");
            int dept = read.nextInt();

            if (dept == 1) {
                getBonus((double) dept);    // should be getBounds
            } else if (dept == 2) {
                getBonus(dept);             // shoul be getBounds
            }
            System.out.println("do you want to continue ? y/n ");
            yORn = read.next.charAt(0);     // should be next()
            if (yORn == 'n') {
                done = true;
            }

        } while (!done);

    }

    public static void fillArray(double[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = read.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    public static void fillArray2(double[] b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {    // a should be b.length
            b[i] = read.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    public static void getBounds(double x) {
        int num;
        for (int i = 1; i <= DEPT1_EMP; i++) {
            System.out.print("How many years have the employee No. " + k);  // k should be i
            num = read.next();   // should be nextInt()
            if (num > 10) {
                salary_Dept1[k] = salary_Dept1[k] + (20 / 100) * salary_Dept1[k];  // salary_Dept1 is not within scope
            }                                                                      // should be declared at static class member
        }

    }

    public static void getBounds(int x) {
        char fORp;
        for (int i = 1; i <= DEPT2_EMP; i++) {
            System.out.print("the empolyee number " + i + " if s/he works full-time or part=time (F/P)?");
            fORp = read.next.charAt(0);   // should be next()
            if (fOrp == 'F') {   // fOrp should be fORp, look at your declaration
                salary_Dept2[i] = salary_Dept2[i] + 700;
            } else if (fOrp == 'P') {
                salary_Dept2[i] = salary_Dept2[i] + 250;  // salary_Dept2 out of scopr
                                                          // should be declared as static class member
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You should really consider using an IDE. If you already are, you really need to learn what the error messages mean.

Comment: thank you so much, but why you changed the name getBounds to getDounds because I have to use overloading I mean I have to use the same name but different type of parameter

Comment: also salary_Dept2 is a global variable is it ?

Comment: It's a typo. Should be `getBounds`

Comment: And no, they are not global. They are declared in the `main`. That means other methods can't use it. You see how you have this `final static int DEPT2_EMP = 500;`. That's global